# Power spectral density of not wide sense stationary

Tags: random-variables, fourier-transform, stationary-processes

For the random variable $w$ with probabilities $P[w=0]=1/4,\ P[w=1]=3/4$, the random process $X(w,t)$ is given
$$X(0,t)=\cos(2\pi t),\quad X(1,t)=\sin(2\pi t).$$
The autocorrelation function of $X(t)$ is
$$E[X(t+\tau)X(t)]=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(4\pi t+2\pi\tau)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi\tau).$$

The usual way to derive power spectral density is Fourier transform of autocorrelation function when the random process is wide-sense stationary. However, this random process is not that case, so I tried to derive the power spectral density through the definition on Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density], but when I tried, it becomes infinite.

Could anyone solve it, or clarify that the power spectral density cannot exist in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process is 1-periodic with probability 1. So I think you should take the Fourier series. Then the power spectrum is the modulus-squared of that.